# C++ Observer design pattern, prevent object from being reallocated

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++17, c++20, c++23

Due to the fact that in some cases the objects are reallocated, for example in the case of std::vector, C++ observable pattern implementation can be problematic:

According to the "Gang of four" book, the implementation for an observable object looks like this:

```
class ObservableSubject {
public:
  virtual ~ObservableSubject() = default;
  virtual void notify() = 0;

protected:
  ObservableSubject() = default;

private:
  std::vector<Observer*> mObservers;
};
```

Where Observer looks like this:

```
class Observer {
public:
  virtual ~Observer() = default;

  virtual void update(ObservableSubject& subject) = 0;

protected:
  Observer() = default;
};
```

Considering this example:

```
class Mapper final: public Observer  {};
```

with the Mapper being held like this `std::vector<Mapper>`, the pointer held in `mObservers` will be invalidated as soon as `std::vector<Mapper>` reallocates the memory.
The solution would be of course to use a pointer(i.e. `std::shared_ptr`) and have `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Mapper>>`. This solution can be problematic as the developer has to remember that Mapper cannot be reallocated.

Is there a way to constraint a class in C++ not to be reallocated?

The implementation in the book:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your belief/assertion that resizing a `std::vector<Observer *>` will reallocate the objects (pointed to by elements of the vector) is incorrect.

Comment: The assumption is that std::vector<Mapper> will reallocate. I added an edit to clarify.

Comment: Yes, it will.  But it reallocates a (dynamically allocated) array of `Observer *` and, as part of reallocating, copies existing values to the reallocated array before releasing the original.    But copying a pointer (or a set of pointers) by value does not affect the objects that those pointers point at.

Comment: If GoF wrote `class ObservableSubject` like that, they aren't good at C++. At a minimum you should `=delete` the copy constructor and copy assignment to get a compilation error when someone tries to copy/move this class. But it might be more desirable instead to implement a meaningful move constructor and move assignment to update the pointer to observer, wherever it's stored.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Implementing a meaningful move constructor would be the right solution I think. I don't know why the implementation from the book is missing this part, maybe it's fixed in a newer revision.

Comment: @Peter It reallocates an array of Mapper objects, the array of Observer* is fixed. Both copying and moving the Mapper objects are problematic in this case. In the copy case, the subject will notify only one of the instances. In the move case it will notify a deleted object.

Comment: Objects in C++ are never reallocated in a sense they would be transferred from one storage to another. A vector within reallocation creates new elements by calling move or copy constructor (plus the original elements are destructed). If you want to avoid this, you can disable both.

Comment: There is no newer edition than the one published in 1994, so I find it difficult to believe that it suggests that particular implementation.

Comment: @molbdnilo Take a look, page 300 http://www.javier8a.com/itc/bd1/articulo.pdf

Comment: I see. So, by "looks like this" you meant "looks somewhat similar to this".

Comment: @molbdnilo I added the exact implementation in the question, I intentionally removed the attach/dettach methods to emphasize the problem.

Comment: Object that are referenced by other components should generally be non-copyable and non-movable, for the exact reason you have discovered.

Answer (score 1):

You might disallow constructors and create a factory returning smart pointer:

```
class Mapper final: public Observer  {
     // Pass-key idiom to allow `std::make_unique` usage
     class private_key {
         private_key() = default;
     };
public:
    Mapper(private_key) {}

    Mapper(const Mapper&) = delete;
    Mapper(Mapper&&) = delete;

    static std::unique_ptr<Mapper> create() { return std::make_unique<Mapper>(private_key{}); }

    // ...
};
```

So address of the object is "stable".